# Rails server crashes due to captcha?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Over the weekend I shut my localhost server down because I wasn't doing anything with it.  However this week I have had a host of issues with booting it back up.  My first problem with something with rmagick, I had to either install(?) or update command line tools, reinstall rmagick and nokogiri.

Now that problem seems to be behind me but every time I run `rails s`

It cashes after boot and I get this error:

```
 => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/tfantina/Documents/Code and Websites/Ruby & Rails Stuff/professor/config/initializers/recaptcha.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `public_key=' for #<Recaptcha::Configuration:0x007fbaa89d09d0> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  public_send
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/recaptcha-4.0.0/lib/recaptcha.rb:30:in `configure'
    from /Users/tfantina/Documents/Code and Websites/Ruby & Rails Stuff/professor/config/initializers/recaptcha.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/tfantina/Documents/Code and Websites/Ruby & Rails Stuff/professor/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/tfantina/Documents/Code and Websites/Ruby & Rails Stuff/professor/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/tfantina/Documents/Code and Websites/Ruby & Rails Stuff/professor/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/tfantina/Documents/Code and Websites/Ruby & Rails Stuff/professor/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I haven't touched that initializer in weeks, I even checked my git status to be sure and nothing has changed.  Any ideas on why this keeps crashing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recaptcha has been updated.

https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

`public_key` to `site_key`

`private_key` to `secret_key`

Change your config/initializers/recaptcha.rb

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.site_key  = 'public key'
  config.secret_key = 'private key'
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have checked that.